# Does ChartJS have an API method for updating the chart instance with a single configuration object?

Tags: javascript, typescript, chart.js

With ChartJS we can create a chart instance like this:

```
const chart = new Chart(ctx, config);
```

If we update the `config` object does ChartJS have a method for performing the update by just passing in the new object?

For example with Apache ECharts we can do it like this:

```
this.chartInstance.setOption(this.options);
```

Comment: _"Does ChartJS have an API method for updating the chart instance configuration with a single call? ... If we update the `config` object does ChartJS have a method for performing the update by just passing in the new object?"_ No

Comment: Yes just passing in the new object - OK - That's what I thought - thanks for confirming.

Comment: You don't typically pass any object, you modify the `Chart` instance, e.g., `chart.data` or `chart.options`, and then call [`chart.update()`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#update-mode)